# Появление и исчезновение окна

Tags: html, css, анимация

Делаю окно, которое должно появиться при загрузке страницы с верху, и также потом через секунд 5 уйти обратно вперёд. Всё это он должен делать автоматически(через секунд 5), и ничего нажимать не надо, чтобы его убрать или чтобы он появился.

Пока окно умеет только вылетать:

`<div className="wrapper"></div>`

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    background-color: #d64259;
    top:30px;
    left: 30%;
    animation: Wrapper 1s;
  }
  @keyframes Wrapper{
    0%{
      transform: translateY(-300px);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">Окно</div>
```

Буду рад помощи, всё лучше сделать на CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете продублировать анимацию, указав свойство задержки ([`animation-delay: 6s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)), запуск анимации "наоборот" ([`animation-direction: reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)) и оставить последний кадр анимации ([`animation-fill-mode: forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode))

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background-color: #d64259;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30%;
  animation: Wrapper 1s, Wrapper 1s 6s reverse forwards;
  /* 6s это задержка, где учитывается время проигрывания первой анимации + ожидание в течении 5 секунд */
}

@keyframes Wrapper {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-300px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">Окно</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо всем! Всё работает!Прекрасно!

Answer (score 6):

Можно немного изменить анимацию и, главное, не забыть добавить `forwards`, чтобы сохранилось состояние после её завершения:

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    background-color: #d64259;
    top:30px;
    left: 30%;
    animation: fade 6s forwards;
  }
  @keyframes fade{
    0%{
      transform: translateY(-300px);
    }
    20% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    80% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(-300px);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```